# ¿Cómo puedo enviar la respuesta de un formulario a una hoja de cálculo diferente al de las respuestas del formulario de google?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Buen día, espero alguien pueda ayudarme con mi duda, soy nuevo en esto de hojas de cálculo de Google y empiezo a automatizar alguna cosas.

Tengo un formulario que recoge solo 3 respuestas,  valido las respuestas  al enviarse el formulario; y la respuesta 2 y 0 las envío a la celda B22 de la hoja activa que es diferente a la hoja de respuestas del formulario. Como soy nuevo en esto, no se que función usar para hacer esto mismo pero enviar las respuestas 2 y 0 a la celda B22 pero de otra hoja de cálculo. Espero me haya explicado y de antemano agradezco su respuesta.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {

var timestamp =e.values[0];
var Contrasena =e.values[1];
var Autoriza =e.values[2];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("B22:B22")
   .setValue(Autoriza +"\n\n"+timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"...pero de otra hoja de cálculo"

Usa [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

Comment: Rubén, muchas gracias por la respuesta, he intentado hacerlo de varias maneras, y quiero pensar que lo estoy haciendo mal por que no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar <    >

Comment: @RicardoSS publica una nueva pregunta donde muestres con lo que estás intentando hacer.

Comment: @RicardoSS Te sugería publicarlo en una nueva pregunta. Es difícil leer código en comentarios, ademàs falta que indiques si ocurre un error y el error textual y si no ocurre un error sería bueno que pusieras El transcript de la ejecución

Comment: ok. gracias, reformulare la pregunta.